# How to get and set different values of two jquery nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

I have two jquery nodes:

```
$result = this._editTime = 
             $("<input>")
               .attr({"type":"number", "style":"display:inline;", "min":"0"})
               .add("<span>&nbsp;d&nbsp;<span>")
               .add("<input type='number' style='display:inline;' , min='0'></input>")
               .add("<span>&nbsp;h&nbsp;<span>");
```

I want to set initial value for both input field, and get the modified value.
if I use

```
$result.val(value)
```

The value of 2 inputs will be the same, but I want to set different to them.
And I also tried:

```
$result.siblings("input")[0].value = days;
$result.siblings("input")[1].value = hours;
```

But system said : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined.

However, I can read value through this method, but the value is not what I modified.

So, how can I set the initial value(different) for this two input fields and get the new value I changed?

Here is the fiddle of the application, you can see the prolme in "Time" column. When I click the row to edit, and the value will disappear and I cannot modified the value as well. 
http://jsfiddle.net/codingbunny/p39kteqh/7/

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the indexes of the elements you need to access because you just built the jQuery object. Just access the `<input>`s directly:

```
$result[0].value = days;
$result[2].value = hours;
```

Example:

```js
var $result = $("<input>").attr({
  "type": "number",
  "style": "display:inline;",
  "min": "0"
}).add("<span>&nbsp;d&nbsp;<span>").add("<input type='number' style='display:inline;' , min='0'></input>").add("<span>&nbsp;h&nbsp;<span>");

var days = 1;
var hours = 2;

$result[0].value = days;
$result[2].value = hours;

$(document.body).append($result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works on setting initial value! But if I modified the value, and try to get new value by this method, it still return me the old value. The fiddle demonstrate the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/codingbunny/p39kteqh/16/

Comment: I believe this answers your question. I'm happy to continue helping you, but please do not expect me to search through a larger codebase to locate another problem and solve it. If you have another question, please create another reduced example and ask the new question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set value as shown below

```
$result.val(value);
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when post the question. I edited my question. I did use this method and it set both input fields same value but I want them different. Thank you for your reply.